# String format in sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, string.format, strftime

In my select query i am using string.format for the where clauses.
When i have strfTime within format i am getting errors.

```
select = String.format(Locale.US, "SELECT %d AS %s, CAST(strftime('%s', START)  AS  integer) AS %s",
                    SORT_ID, SORT_ORDER_ID, SORT_ORDER_DATE);
```

// select = "SELECT " + SORT_ID + " AS SORT_ORDER_ID, CAST(strftime('%s', START)  AS  integer) AS SORT_ORDER_DATE";

The commented line without string.format works. But when i add string.format i am getting **MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'**

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert a datestring into an integer????? and why are you converting the column names? they are all strings. By the way, you are renaming the first column to another name... again, why? I have the feeling you aren't much comfortable with databases...

Comment: You have 1 `%d` and 3 `%s` which requires 4 args. Although you only have 3.

Comment: i am not renaming first column , its actually a constant integer , adding that to cursor result to be used later for my sorting. Same is the reason to convert the date . @rotwang

Comment: @Enzokie CAST(strftime('%s', START) here this START is the arg for %s . But i am sure this is not the way i have to use it

Comment: `i am not renaming first column` Well, you actually **ARE**: `SELECT %d AS %s ...` renames the first column to another name (`AS` means "rename to"). Therefore you are saying: `SELECT Column_A renamed AS Some_Other_Name ...`. Moreover, `"SELECT %d AS %s ...` should be: `"SELECT %s AS %s ...`

Comment: Because, you know, all column names are ***strings***.

Comment: In addition `integer or INTEGER` is a reserved word so you cannot use it as alias like `AS integer`.

Comment: @Enzokie I guess the OP has a momentary brain fog. Probably they are  confused about *SQL syntax* in general and *casting* in specific.

Comment: @Rotwang more patience my friend :)

Comment: @Enzokie `INTEGER` is not a [keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format()` function uses `%` as replacement markers; it expects a string for the `%s` in the call to `strftime()`.

But you don't want this to be replaced by `format()`.
To get `format()` to output a single `%` character, you have to escape it by doubling it in the format string:

```
String.format("... strftime('%%s', START) ...", ...);
```

Comment: This saved my day . Thanks a lot for not ignoring inspite of all the comments above

Answer (score 2):

**Your format string**

`"SELECT %d AS %s, CAST(strftime('%s', START)  AS  integer) AS %s"`

1. `%d`
2. `%s`
3. `%s`
4. `%s`

**Parameters**

1. `SORT_ID`
2. `SORT_ORDER_ID`
3. `SORT_ORDER_DATE`

**Problem**

Your format requires *four parameters*. But you only provide *three parameters*. Correct this.

I think the parameter for the last alias `AS %s` is missing

**Additional-Problem**

`CAST(strftime('%s', START)` It is not a string for format.

**Try this.**

```
String QUERY_INTEGER = "CAST(strftime('%s', START)";    
select = String.format(Locale.US, "SELECT %d AS %s, %s  AS  integer) AS %s",
                SORT_ID, SORT_ORDER_ID, QUERY_CAST, SORT_ORDER_DATE);
```

Comment: CAST(strftime('%s', START) here this START is the arg for %s . But i am sure this is not the way i have to use it. So i want to know how do i combine strftime in string.format

Comment: to escape your `%s`parameter inside your string format you have to use `%%s` so `"SELECT %d AS %s, CAST(strftime('%%s', START)  AS  integer) AS %s"`

Comment: will try this later and see if it works @EthanChoi . Thanku